# Why does a LR(1) DFA doesn't have a Shift/Reduce conflict?

Tags: compiler-construction, dfa, lr-grammar

Given this grammar:
[image]

For the LR(**0**) DFA I can clearly see why this is a Shift/Reduce conflict:

[image]

*(partial DFA)*

But I can't understand why the LR(**1**) DFA solves the problem?

[image]
*(partial DFA)*

For me this is still a shift reduce conflict since the lookahead symbol is exactly the same for the **B** rule? How should the LR(1) parser distinguish them, but not the LR(0) one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can only reduce *B*→ε if the lookahead is <kbd>a</kbd>.

In LR(0) you cannot take lookahead into account, but in LR(1) you can decide based on the next input symbol, and here the rule is simple: if the next symbol is <kbd>b</kbd>, shift it, and if it is <kbd>a</kbd>, do the epsilon reduction of *B*.